# Mac suddenly lost the ability to connect to apps via ports

Tags: networking, macos, port-forwarding

Last week, I upgraded to the latest version of Transmission BT (4.0.2), and it suddenly stopped being able to connect to peers. I've tried all the usual suspects: port forwarding, making sure UPnP is enabled on the router, etc.

- Under Transmission Settings -> Network: Peer Listening Port says closed.
- Canyouseeme can't see any forwarded ports I set up. I even set up port forwarding for a little python app and couldn't see it from the internet.
- I tried other torrent clients and they have the same problem.
- I tried upgrading to ventura, uninstalling transmission
- Mac firewall is off

I noticed that the problem isn't limited to Transmission, I also can't connect to Steam, and the Signal app on my mac can't connect either.

Any idea what's going on?

---

**Update**: I tried checking the WAN address of the router. It looks like it's using an IP6 address: `2607:fb90:87a0:4a0a:e0a8:5ea5:6a85:b7b0`. But https://canyouseeme.org/ shows an IP4 address `172.56.208.160`. I don't know enough about IP6 addresses to understand the implications of this.

**Solution**: I had to force my router to only use IP4, and now it's working again. In this case, it's a mobile hotspot from Calyx, and I had to make a new APN that was IP4 only.

Comment: Does your router still report a WAN IP address that is in fact a public IP address?

Comment: Try to reboot your router and Mac and retest.

Comment: @user1686 The router is reporting an IP6 address, see update above.

Comment: IPv4 and IPv6 are not mutually exclusive. It's useful to know that IPv6 is available, but it's generally not "instead of IPv4" – though there are cases of that as well – but "in addition to IPv4"...